# Offloading db connection to helper class, should I be using db.dispose in each method?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

I'm developing a dashboard right now that is becoming quite complex.  I'm using Asp.Net MVC 5 with EF 6.

My general architecture is;

The controller instantiates a ViewModel which I populate with objects from my Helper class to pass to the view.  The helper class houses the db connection and methods that I expose which house my linq queries.  I set it up this way to keep the controllers light weight because when its all said and done, I'll have around 20 objects I'll be handing off to the view via the ViewModel.  I'm not sure what pattern this most aligns to these days but I like this approach because it helps keep me organized. (feel free to provide constructive feedback)

My question is; because I'm not accessing the database from the controller,  should I be calling db.dispose() after each method executes in the Helper Class?

Thanks in advance!

Here's a sample;

CONTROLLER

```
 public class DashboardController : Controller
{
    Metrics metrics = new Metrics();
    MainDashboardViewModel vm = new MainDashboardViewModel();

    // GET: Dashboard
    public ActionResult Index(string region, string businessUnit, DateTime? startDate, DateTime? endDate)
    {
        ViewBag.Dash = "active";

        vm.Region = region;
        vm.BusinessUnit = businessUnit;
        vm.StartDate = startDate;
        vm.EndDate = endDate;

        //get average seat price
        vm.AvgSeatPrice = metrics.GetAvgSeatPrice(vm.BusinessUnit, vm.Region, vm.StartDate, vm.EndDate);

        //...lots more removed for brevity

        return View(vm);            
    }
}
```

Helper Class

```
public class Metrics
{
    private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();

       //AVERAGE SEAT PRICE
    public string GetAvgSeatPrice(string bu, string region, DateTime? startDate, DateTime? endDate)
    {

    var averageSeatPrice = (from r in db.Registrations
                            where
                                 (bu == "All" || r.BusinessUnit.Equals(bu)) &&
                                 (region == "All" || r.Region.Equals(region)) &&
                                 (startDate == null || r.StartDate >= startDate) &&
                                 (endDate == null || r.EndDate <= endDate) &&
                                 r.ActualPrice > 0 &&
                                 !r.Status.Equals("cancelled")

                            select r.ActualPrice).Average();

    var AvgSeatPrice = "$" + string.Format("{0:0.00}", averageSeatPrice);

    return AvgSeatPrice;
   }

 //...lots more metrics methods removed for brevity
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be fine if you are not disposing yourself explicitly but it is recommended to use `using(){}` in order to have at least implicit disposition.

```
public string GetAvgSeatPrice(string bu, string region, DateTime? startDate, DateTime? endDate)
{
    double averageSeatPrice = 0;

    using(var db = new ApplicationDbContext())
    {
        averageSeatPrice = (from r in db.Registrations
                                where
                                     (bu == "All" || r.BusinessUnit.Equals(bu)) &&
                                     (region == "All" || r.Region.Equals(region)) &&
                                     (startDate == null || r.StartDate >= startDate) &&
                                     (endDate == null || r.EndDate <= endDate) &&
                                     r.ActualPrice > 0 &&
                                     !r.Status.Equals("cancelled")

                                select r.ActualPrice).Average();
    }

    var AvgSeatPrice = "$" + string.Format("{0:0.00}", averageSeatPrice);

    return AvgSeatPrice;
}
```

For more you can go through this: http://blog.jongallant.com/2012/10/do-i-have-to-call-dispose-on-dbcontext.html#.U6WdzrGEeTw

Comment: Thank you.  How would you structure the 'using' if you want the db to be private and available to all the methods in the class?

Comment: @JReam You can have `db` private like you have now and then just do `using(db){ //do sth }` in each method where you need the context.

Comment: If I wrap a using(db){} around my code inside each method, the connection is disposed after GetAvgSeatPrice().  If I have a main private ApplicationDBContext db...  and I have methods that are called sequentially where each method uses db, how would you use 'using' in a case like this?

Comment: @JReam In that case, you can either initialize your context in each method `using(var db = new ApplicationContext()) {  }` or if you want to keep your context private and global then you can implement `IDisposible` on your `Metrics` helper class and call it manually from your controller `metrics.Dispose();`

Comment: @JReam Your `Metrics` helper class can be called a Repository so better follow that pattern : http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wriju/archive/2013/08/23/using-repository-pattern-in-entity-framework.aspx

Comment: Thanks, Ibrahim!  You've been more helpful than anyone else I've ran into on here, greatly appreciate it!

Comment: @Ibrahim; Would this be the proper implementation of IDisposable?  I'm following the logic of a scaffolded controller.  I do not see it explicitly being called in the controller so I'm assuming that Dispose() gets called when the class object has been used? public class Metrics : IDisposable
    {
        private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();

        //method 1 using db

        //metod 2 using db

        public void Dispose()
        {
            db.Dispose();
        }
    }

Comment: @JReam Glad I could I help. Also I am looking to make 1000 points mark here in SO :) Anyways, you thought right and you can also see a code sample here I [uploaded](http://codeshare.io/De3A4) for you and also see the article I referred earlier.